# How do I make IDEA/Android Studio recognize my unit test folder when using Gradle?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So I've successfully managed to make Gradle run standard Junit tests for my Android project by following [this guide](http://tryge.com/2013/02/28/android-gradle-build/), but I'm struggling getting Gradle to generate my .IML file so that IDEA recognizes my unit test folder. It is not green in the project tree.

So this is an excerpt of my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
    }
}

task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    description = "run unit tests"
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

This is the line I in the .IML file I *want* Gradle to generate, but it doesn't:

```
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
```

If I add it manually, it's removed by Gradle any time I make any change to build.gradle, so that sucks.

I also tried adding these lines to the build file, without any difference:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module.testSourceDirs += file('scr/test/java')
}
```

I press the refesh button each time I do any changes so that the IML file will be regenerated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK it's not so easy. In the company I work guys made it possible to run tests from AS but the code isn't refreshed (it must be rebuild manually using gradle). It's all a mess.. If You succeed share the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using Android Studio 1.3.2 with Gradle 1.3.0 and found that I have to change the Test Artifact to Unit Tests in the Build Variants tab. After doing that the IDE works as expected. I found the information at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support.

Comment: Yea this option didn't exist when I asked the question, but is definitely the correct solution now. The `idea` plugin as mentioned in the question is no longer needed either (although it can be useful)

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble when I don't use the default gradle file structure.  Try putting your tests under "src/androidTest/java" and then modify your "build.gradle" file to include test information in the "defaultConfig"

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testPackageName "com.yourpackage.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        testFunctionalTest true
    }
}
```

This works for me - I'm able to run tests from inside Android Studio.